# How to get all files in google drive, who don't have parents?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to get all files, who don't have parents using google drive rest api query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no query to find "orphaned" files. If you're looking for files that the user owns, you'd need to do files.list() with a query of `'me' in owners` and fields value of `files(id,parents),nextPageToken` then locally filter down to files with no parents.

Comment: Guy Smith's answer below is a better option now.

Comment: When I do `me in owners` I get a bunch of extra files, I think it is giving me all files in the entire account. Is it possible to request just root folders and those that don't have parents?

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible as explained in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339?hl=en). To return all orphaned files you own use the following search query: [`is:unorganized owner:me`](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=is:unorganized%20owner:me).

You can leave off the second part if you want all files owned by anyone, or replace the `me` with any specific users email address to get their orphaned files.

**NOTE: This is using the Web UI and *not* the API. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025546/google-drive-api-list-files-with-no-parent/48958491) shows options available through the API.**

Comment: Those flags are not available through the v2 and v3 API.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Google uses an `unparented = true` search phrase, but this does not appear to be available in the V2 or V3 REST APIs.

Answer (score -2):

If by "don't have parents" you mean "aren't in a folder", then such files have 'root' as a default parent so you can search on that.

Comment: You can search for root ```'root' in parents```, but it doesn't help, since orphaned files do NOT have root as a parent.

Comment: yes I agree. I was making an assumption about what the OP mean by "no parent". Jay's answer is the safest option, whereas mine was assuming that by "no parents", the OP means "files not moved to a subfolder"