# Which query string for DriveApp.searchFiles() mimics the Drive search "is:unorganized"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to recreate in Google App Script the search  "is:unorganized", which would be entered in the Google Drive search bar.  My goal is to find orphaned files in a manner other than finding the parents of all files and selecting those which are 'null'.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) the queries are written according to these [rules](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

However, it's not clear to me how to test for "unorganized".  I've tried:

```
var orphans = DriveApp.searchFiles(q)
```

with the following qs

```
"unorganized=true"
"'unorganized' in parents"
```

For the first, I get the error "Invalid argument: q" because the query is invalid, and in the 2nd I get an error saying the ID doesn't exist because there is no folder called "unorganized".

Does anyone know the q that corresponds to "is:unorganized"?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all files in google drive, who don't have parents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127219/how-to-get-all-files-in-google-drive-who-dont-have-parents)

Comment: There's no API way to do anything like a single "is:unorganized" query

Comment: The question is specifically related to reproducing the "is:unorganized" query is Google Drive (further info: as a possible improvement to what I have currently which gets the parents of all files and looks at what returns "null").

Furthermore, there is an API way to do things like "is:unorganized".  It's explained via the links above.  For example. I can reproduce "is:starred".

Comment: I've edited my post to make it clearer I'm after the relevant search query, not just generally asking how to find orphaned files.

Comment: Taking @Paul's hint to look for any files/folders without a parent, I whipped up a script to do exactly that, populate them into a spreadsheet, and send an email if any were found.  Shared here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N7CMAalpdVQkIZ1j9uIOHbhKRacB2Af9rf6n1TwG-t8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is to find orphaned files in a manner other than finding the parents of all files and selecting those which are 'null'.

There's no way currently in `DriveApp.searchFiles(query)` to compose a query that reproduces the `is:unorganized` Drive UI search. That's because the [Drive API (DriveAPP uses V2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) search fields and operators don't give you the breath of functionality required.

There is however a search that will improve upon a scan of all files, and that is using a search query as follows:

```
var potentialOrphans = DriveApp.searchFiles('not "root" in parents');
```

This gives you all files except those that are children of My Drive. This is a smaller starting list that you could potentially then iterate through to find those files that have no parents.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code you suggest gives all files which are not direct children of root, which in my case where the files I'm dealing with are numerous and organised in a folder hierarchy, is actually all the files anyway.  I'll accept the answer because you've confirmed there isn't a way at present to mimic the desired query and you've suggested something that might be helpful for others with a similar problem.